# Todos os métodos de collection e List são implementados na ArrayList?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, collection

As interfaces `Collection` e `List` (por exemplo) têm muitos métodos.
Por que a classe `ArrayList` implementa só alguns métodos dessas interfaces? Não funciona como herança que as subclasses herdam os métodos da classe mãe?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse trecho refere-se à classe `ArrayList` e foi retirado da [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Comment: Muitos métodos são implementados a partir da especificação da interface e não herdados. Os que são implementados não aparecem na listagem de métodos herdados de outras classes, aparece somente a declaração de que a classe implementa a interface, no topo da documentação e no detalhamento do método. Por exemplo, o método [ArrayList.remove(int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove(int)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Curioso, o meu não tem:

[image: Trecho retirado da documentação mostrando que está diferente do que o AP mostrou]
https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html

Tem uma explicação, eu estou usando a versão mais recente que o termo mudou porque a documentação é gerada de forma diferente, não é apenas cosmética, houve uma mudança semântica.

Isso é uma questão de intepretação de texto, importante para usar bem documentação. E por isso eu considero uma das perguntas mais importantes já postadas no SOpt ultimamente e até de certa forma de todos os tempos, ainda que não tão bem formulada.

Tudo o que for fazer de trabalho qualificado precisa aprender fazer antes. Precisa ver se tem um manual, uma documentação. E o AP fez isso, é um alento.

Até para usar o SOpt as pessoas deveriam fazer isto. Uma pena que muitos não o fazem, então não se qualificação e acabam tendo uma experiência ruim, porque ações intuitivas muitas vezes não funcionam. E como é insensato fazer assim geralmente a pessoa se revolta e fica agressiva por não obter o que deseja. As pessoas sofreriam menos lendo como usar o SOpt.

Esta pergunta é pertinente porque não tem um manual, uma documentação óbvia e fácil de achar de como interpretar a documentação. Sim, para entender a documentação precisa ver a documentação dela. É assim que programadores, engenheiros, cientistas e outros profissionais operam, o resto é enganador.

O que esses trechos estão dizendo?

Alguns métodos da classe documentada (`ArrayList`) não foram implementadas nessa classe, mas os métodos estão presentes já que é uma exigência da interface. Porém a implementação veio de algum outro lugar (no caso de `AbstractList`), e foi destacado esse fato, que na verdade a documentação específica dessa implementação é a mesma da implementação real porque não houve mudança.

Então o `size()` por exemplo, não está aí porque a classe sendo vista implementou sua própria versão do método e documenta mais abaixo como está, o que provavelmente é diferente da implementação que foi feita em outro lugar.

O Javadoc permite omitir a descrição de um método já implementado antes em outro lugar, te obrigando ir lá ver como é o comportamento documentado. Pior? O *link* está ali para clicar e ir para a doc. Deixa a documentação mais limpa. Então separou o que é algo específico da classe e o que veio de outro lugar.

Aí você vai reclamar que o `equals()` está na lista principal e na que delegada. O que acontece? A hora que eu descobrir eu te conto! :D Realmente essa não achei nada confiável. Vi que [tem classe que isto não ocorre](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashSet.html). Ambas usam implementação herdada. E muda onde aparece na documentação dependendo da versão, a 17 não tem ele listado em `List`, ao contrário da 7 por exemplo, só em `AbstractList`, e na 7 não é listado na principal.